# Loop, tab.Length and infinitely many zeros

Tags: loops, infinite-loop

In void `A_shaped()` is an error in loop.

I think this is a problem with the variable `Tab.Length`, but I don't understand why.

Can somebody explain it to me?

When the program is starting loop is filled with only zero... What can I replace this variable? Below I send code on the Coctail sort in tab `A_shaped`. The code is truncated.

Sorry, this is my first post and one of my first programs.

```
     static void A_shaped(int[] Tab)
            {
                int j = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < Tab.Length ; i += 2)
                {
                    Tab[j] = i;
                    j++;
                }

                for (int i = Tab.Length; i > 0; i -= 2)
                {
                    Tab[j] = i;
                    j++;
                }
            }


    static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                int[] Tab = new int[8] { 25000, 50000, 75000, 100000, 125000, 150000, 175000, 200000 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)

    {
    int[] a_shaped = new int[Tab[i]];

                    CocktailSort(a_shaped);

                    foreach (int a in a_shaped)
                        Console.WriteLine(a);

}
```

Comment: Hva you tried to print `Tab.length` to see if the problem actually comes from this value?

Comment: Also you should describe exactly what your program currently does, and how you wan't it to work. Because as it, this question is probably impossible to answer.

Comment: Yes my foreach is that coz i want  see actually problem.

 I want make e shaped tab from this 8 elements in tab

When i use specific number it work. But when i use "tab/Length." i have then infinite loop.  This is some solution but i dont want write only numbers ... but i want make a universaly code

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to follow your logic. Honestly I am not sure to understand what you tried to do, but I think you are mistaking on basically everything.

**Let's take your `main()` for example :**

First you are creating an `int` array, called `Tab` and containing height values. No problem with that.

```
int[] Tab = new int[8] { 25000, 50000, 75000, 100000, 125000, 150000, 175000, 200000 };
```

Let's talk about your `for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)` loop now. Here is what you are in the loop the first time, when `i` is equal to 0:

First of all, doing this : `int[] a_shaped = new int[Tab[i]];` you are creating another `int` array, called `a_shaped`, and that has a size of the `int` found at the index `i` in `Tab`. So basically, you're creating an array of size 25000.

Then, you try to sort this array `a_shaped` passing to `CocktailSort` function. But you never initialized it, so your `a_shaped` array is containing 25000 integers that are equal to zero.

Then, finally, you're printing the content of `a_shaped` with the following lines :

```
foreach (int a in a_shaped)
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

This prints the 25000 integers contained in `a_shape` which are all equal to zero. This made you think it was an infinite loop, or a bug, but it's not. It's simply printing all the 0 contained in `a_shape`, as you asked.

**Conclusion :**

Whatever you think you are doing you are not. You're showing a function `static void A_shaped(int[] Tab)` but you never called it. You simply created a **variable**, called almost the same way `a_shaped`. You also forgot to intialize it, and gave it a size that you probably didn't want it to have. And then, by printing these huge arrays filled with 0, you thought you were facing an infinite loop, but you were just printing tons of zero.

No offense but I would suggest you to train on simplier programs first to learn the language, and then come back to this.

Comment: No problem, and if there is anything you don't understand, just ask me :)